# Not the answer you're looking for? copy spacing bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, whitespace

The "Not the answer you're looking for?" text below a question's answers is missing a space before the next sentence. (between "for?" and "Browse")

[image: Visual screenshot]

[image: Screenshot of source]

Answer (score 5):

A fix for this will be rolling out soon, should be deployed in build `rev 2020.4.1.36448` or later.

This was caused by a difference in new-line / whitespace handling in the AspNetCore Razor engine.